# Dynamically generated form tracking changes but returning undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm using a class to dynamically generate a form made up of text inputs. I will be storing the data in an array in my state. My `handleInputChange` function is tracking the data, but it fails at the `list[index][name] = value` part of my HandleInputChange method. The error is `cannot set property playerName of undefined`. Can anyone help explain how I can get this working?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Form extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      playerNames: [],
    };

    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleInputChange = (e, index) => {
    const { playerNames } = this.state;
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    const list = [...playerNames];
    list[index][name] = value;
    this.setState({ playerNames: this.list });
  };

  handleClick = () => {
    const { playerNames } = this.state;
    this.setState([...this.playerNames, { playerName: "" }]);
  };

  render() {
    const { playerNames } = this.state;
    const { noPlayers, handleClick } = this.props;
    let multiples = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < noPlayers; i++) {
      multiples.push(<div></div>);
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <form>
          <label className="block">
            <>
              {multiples.map((input, index) => (
                <input
                  key={index}
                  name="playerName"
                  className="form-input mt-1 block w-full"
                  type="text"
                  placeholder={"Player " + (index + 1)}
                  value={index.playerName}
                  onChange={(e) => this.handleInputChange(e, index)}
                />
              ))}
            </>
          </label>
          <button
            className="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-400 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 border-b-4 border-blue-700 hover:border-blue-500 rounded"
            onClick={handleClick}
          >
            Submit
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Form;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list[index][name] = value
```

fails because there are no initial objects inside the array.

Assuming you want playerNames to be something like

```
[
  { playername: "input1 value" },
  { playername: "input2 value" },
  { playername: "input3 value" },
];
```

You need to change

```
const list = [...playerNames];
list[index][name] = value;
this.setState({ playerNames: this.list });
```

to create a new list with new objects every time

```
const list = [...playerNames];
list[index] = {[name]:value};
this.setState({ playerNames: list });
```